# Good way to create a simple website password?

Tags: javascript, html, server

I'm making a website and there is a page on said website which I would like only certain people to access, with a password. I was wondering the best way to go about it simply and securely, and would love some example code if any exists.

To clarify, I would like to add a feature to a page on my website which prevents anyone visiting the site from going to that page unless they enter a password. I'm mostly looking for HTML, JS, or JQuery solutions, as this is only going to be for the users of the website.

Comment: Are you *developing* this website? Just HTML/Javascript (that is, no server side)? Then it is probably ServerFault question, depending on your web server. As is, this question seems to be impossible to answer

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way that I've come across is using an `htpasswd` file (which looks very similar to `/etc/passwd` if you are familiar with that), then setting up your webserver to point at it.

```sh
# create htpasswd file
htpasswd -c /path/htpasswd

# add user to htpasswd file (you'll be prompted for password)
htpasswd /path/htpasswd  loginuser
```

Within your `nginx.conf` , set it up like this

```
server {
    listen 80 yourserver;
    listen [::]80 yourserver ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/yourserver;
    index index.html;

    location /public {
        # ...
    }

    # everything under /private requires a login
    location /private {
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /path/htpasswd;
    }
}
```

There's a really good tutorial on this setup, that I shamelessly robbed for this answer here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Then for anything over/above that, nginx's documentation is excellent as well (if that is the webserver you are using).

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html

One trap with this setup is that nginx only allows password hashes that are supported by your operating system's crypt module. So linux for example wouldn't necessarily have bcrypt, but most of the BSDs would. You can find what your OS's crypt module supports using `man crypt` .

|

If you're looking for something where you have a little more control, you can have a URL that you `GET` a website with form data, which `POST`s the login information to a URL you can handle the login details yourself. This is python/flask - I'm not sure it is what you are looking for bsaed on your tags but it may still be helpful.

https://pythonspot.com/login-authentication-with-flask/

I hope this was helpful :) good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what frameworks, applications etc. you are using to create your website, and If you want create an account system or just a protected area, there are many different ways.

### 1. .htaccess:

Assuming you are using a NCSA-compatible webserver such as apache and want to restrict access to a certain path, the simplest (yet by far not safest) way to do that would be to use a simple `.htaccess`-file.
simply put a file with that exact name into the folder you want to protect with following content:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Enter Credentials Here"
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

and create a `.htpasswd` file in a safe place containing

```
username:password
```

or, if you care about people hacking your server getting the password:

```
username:hash
```

you can generate hashes using online-`.htpasswd`-generators.
**Make sure to enter the path to your .htpasswd correctly into your .htaccess!**

The .htaccess file will make the server ask for *basic* username/password authentication, show the message *"Enter Credentials Here"* to the user and require the users browser to send any *valid* credentials to your server. Valid credentials mean any username/password-pair in your .htpasswd file. Just know that the user's browser will always send the credentials to your server unencrypted, so make sure to enable https, if you care about the password not being stolen from your users. And tell them not to write it down etc. basic password safety.

### 2. Fancy Account System using SQL

This is more complicated an probably not what you want, so I will just give basic advice: Read about sql injection and make sure you fully understand it and how to avoid it. Read about password hashing and salting. Read about safe passwords (phrases) to advice your users. Read about html forms and how to parse them using your framework. Read about encryption. Then create a concept that fits your needs and implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP then this is simple solution:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST["password"])){
   header("location:pwdnotcorrect.php");
return;
}
$pwd=$_POST["password"];
if($pwd!="yourpassword"){
   header("location:pwdnotcorrect.php");
   return;
}?>
<!--Your HTML Code starts here--->
```

Send POST request with password to this page using form

If password not correct then this page redirect you to new page.